# Best best way to wrap/override the current_user method from the devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, devise

A common pattern is to use `current_user` in many places, but check whether it is set.

```
if current_user
  #your code
end
```

But instead of injecting an if check just about every time you want to use `current_user`, **how** and **where** can you wrap the current_user method in a different method ONCE, so that the you won't have to deal with your code breaking due to a nil value for devise's default `current_user` method?

Comment: Thing like your magic method you need create own.

Comment: That is already known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **current_user** method is added to **ApplicationController**, then I think you can override it in ApplicationController doing somethig like:

```
# in application_controller.rb
alias_method :devise_current_user, :current_user
def current_user
  if ...#your validation
    devise_current_user # || User.new    # <-- or whatever other non-nil result
  end  
end
```

Comment: I tried doing it in the helper. Why does it not work if defined here?

Comment: Why do methods defined in the application controller behave as universally callable helpers, rather than actions? It is a controller, after all.

Comment: Actually, this pattern still doesn't handle the other case where there is no value. you'd need an else statement....

Comment: Well, I just abbreviated the solution. But yes, you need an else. That's where you should return some other kind of user (like a visitor user or something). But you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom classes that have the methods you are trying to use on `current_user` throughout your application is one way.

http://littlelines.com/blog/2013/06/22/how-to-guard-against-ruby-nil-errors/

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to account for nil value possibilities while working ruby, you're going to be swimming upstream, and become very frustrated. I know I've had similar feelings. It can be really annoying to write:

```
if current_user && current_user.attr == 'val'
```

But I've developed ways to make that less awkward over time...

--edit to show some of the things I do to avoid this--

I often do some of these things. This isn't necessarily a recommendation, or a best practice, but I find that it makes my code less verbose and more readable sometimes

If I expect an array, but the array might be nil:

```
my_array ||= []
```

That way I can safely do things that require array-ness, usually when this is needed in various places in the scope.

```
my_array.size
```

and not have things choke.

In a similar way I might do

```
car ||= Car.new
```

Then I can treat car like any car object. But I probably wouldn't do this with current_user, though.

Comment: care to outline what those ways are? very curious. This is my initial exploration of this topic myself, and this seems like a very elegant and DRY pattern. I'd love to hear others.

Comment: i'll take the experience as that, but i will still question and explore it empirically and logically for myself.

What are some situations where having a nil for current_user is better than not?

Every time i've used it so far, it breaks my app, since i'm usually calling methods on `current_user`'s return value.

Wouldn't a pretty good way be to have this non-nil-returning method, and the devise's default current_user method?

Comment: the method could be designed the way it is because it would be too assuming to implement other retrun values, like a guest user (which may vary widely depending on the designer and app requirements), or false. Who is to say nil was chosen over other values like false for a good reason? Until you know the design issues, and landscape of most common and sensible usage, it could be that it was arbitrarily chosen over false, or other values. Simply relying on the "it is the way it is for a reason" argument is insufficient, and generally speaking the wrong message to preach, imo. (e.g. ruby vs C++)

Comment: While the status quo argument is not logically tight, it is probabilistically right. I see your point.

I'd love to know what those reasons are.

Comment: In ruby culture a method with a ? (e.g. current_user?) would return a boolean, and current_user would return the value, which in some cases it is nil. I'd recommend you write your code to check if there is a user, and then do user-specific things in one block, and things to do when there is no signed-in user in another block. The method current_user for Devise doesn't mean current "site" user, it means the user that is currently logged in.